# How do I conditionally render from three different options in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to conditionally render in React Native, but there are three different options: loading screen, the user has no messages, or display all the users messages. I have a variable called `conversations` which is fetched from my database, but before the fetch completes it is `null`, so I want to display a loading indicator. After the fetch is complete, I want to display a message if the user has no current chats, or display a table containing all the users chats if the user does have existing chats. My thought was something like this:

```js
return (
  <View>
    {conversations ? conversations.length === 0 ? (
      <Text>You have no messages.</Text>
    ) : (
      <ConversationTable conversations={conversations} />
    ) : (
      <ActivityIndicator />
    )}
  </View>
)
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: It might be more clear to do the branching logic outside of the JSX (but still in the render method) instead of inline. EG: `if (conversations && conversations.length) return (<View><Text></Text></View>);`, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, if branch inside the JSX could bring some messy, and pretty confuse to trace code complicate view.

So my suggestion is put your if branch outside of the `return` called, something like this:

```
render() { 
   ...
   let view = null;
   if (conversation == null) {
           view = <ActivityIndicator />
   } else {
       if (conversation.length == 0) 
           view = <Text>You have no messages.</Text>
       else
           view = <ConversationTable conversations={conversations} />
   }       

   ...
   return (
       <View>
           {view}
       </View>
   )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
return (
  <View>
    {conversations === null && <LoadingIndicator />} //The loading indicator will be present only when conversartions is null
    {conversations !== null && conversations.length === 0 ? ( // The conversations.length will be evaluated only when conversations is different to null
      <Text>You have no messages.</Text>
    ) : (
      <ConversationTable conversations={conversations} />
    )}
  </View>
)
```

Comment: This actually does not work because if `conversations` is null then the `conversations !== null && conversations.length === 0` will evaluate to false which will cause the `ConversationTable` to be rendered.

Answer (score 1):

You can go like this

```
{conversations ? (
            {conversations.length===0? (
                <Text>You have no messages.</Text>
            ):(
                <ConversationTable conversations={conversations} />
            )}
        ) :(
            <ActivityIndicator />
        )}
```

Comment: There is a syntax error with this code, can you nest JSX expressions like that?